# Dense basic open set contained in dense open subset

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

For an affine variety $X$ with coordinate ring $A$ it is not hard to see that for $g\in A$ the basic open set (or distinguished open set) $$D(g):=\{ P\in X | g(P)\neq 0\}$$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $g$ is not a zero divisor in $A$.

Now let $U\subset X$ be a dense open subset. It should be true that $U$ contains one of the dense $D(g)$. Is this easy to see? Is it possible to prove this without using any scheme theory?

Comment: I'm confused, the classical affine varieties (those defined as algebraic subsets of $\mathbb A^n$) usually have in their definition "irreducible algebraic subset", which implies that the coordinate ring is an integral domain, yet you speak about zero divisors of $A$. It is as if you had done scheme theory but yet still didn't want to use it.. in scheme theory, one learns that the open sets $D(g)$ form a basis for the topology of the affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, where $g$ ranges over all elements of $A$. This would answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, so I think what is going on here is that I am not necessarily assuming my affine variety $X$ to be irreducible, but rather I am just defining it as the (not necessarily irreducible) zero set of some polynomials. So the coordinate ring may have zero divisors.

Comment: Okay... in this case it would be more appropriate to call it an affine scheme over a field, because the term affine variety is reserved for "varieties that are affine", and any reasonable definition of a variety assumes it is integral. In Hartshorne for instance, a variety over a field $k$ is an integral separated scheme of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ ; the important part for you is that an affine integral scheme comes from an integral domain. But again this is just a technicality, the point is I understand what you say now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ be the minimal primes of $A$. Next let $U=X - Z$ with $I \subseteq A$ an ideal of $A$ and $Z=V(I)$. Now as $U$ is dense in $X$ we have $I \not\subseteq P_i$ for all $i$. Therefore $I \not\subseteq P_1 \cup \cdots \cup P_r$ by the prime avoidance lemma. Now $P_1 \cup \cdots \cup P_r$ is the set of zero-divisors of $A$. (More generally the set of zero divisors of an arbitrary noetherian ring is the union of all its associated primes. But here all associated primes are minimal, as $X$ is a variety, therefore $A$ is a reduced ring).

So there is a $f$ in $I$ that is no zero-divisor of $A$. The $D(f)$ is the basic open set sought for.